# How do I have two RadioControls in my custom Gutenberg block?

Tags: block-editor

Sorry if this is a silly question but I am very new to Wordpress and I am very new to Gutenberg Blocks...

So, I created a new block using `npx @wordpress/create-block`, In my custom block I wish to add some radio buttons to determine css modifiers that I will store in my attributes object. Here is edit.js code, which I have simplified for readability.

```
export default function Edit(props) {
    const [ option, setOption ] = useState( props.attributes.blockType || '' );

    const optionDir = useState( props.attributes.blockType || '' ).option;

    return (
        <div { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <div>
                <RadioControl
                    label="Set the style of the block"
                    selected={ option }
                    options={ [
                        { label: 'default - #40ADAD', value: '' },
                        { label: 'kleidershrank - #0D6575', value: 'uber-mich--kleidershrank' },
                        { label: 'homeoffice - #D5B46E', value: 'uber-mich--homeoffice' },
                        { label: 'umzug - #FF7161', value: 'uber-mich--umzug' },
                        { label: 'pricing - #143F6B', value: 'uber-mich--pricing' }
                    ] }
                    onChange={ ( value ) => {
                        setOption( value );
                        props.setAttributes({blockType: value  })
                    } }
                />

                <RadioControl
                    label="Reverse order of the block "
                    selected={ optionDir }
                    options={ [
                        { label: 'image first', value: '' },
                        { label: 'text first', value: ' uber-mich__list--reverse' },

                    ] }
                    onChange={ ( value ) => {
                        setOption( value );
                        props.setAttributes({direction: value  })
                    } }
                />
                </div>
                <div className={`uber-mich ${props.attributes.blockType || ''}`}>
                   <div className={`uber-mich__list ${props.attributes.direction || ''}`}>
                   </div>
                </div>
    <!-- the rest of the block -->
    );
}
```

I know I am doing something very wrong here, I am confused with the `option` and `setOption` properties that are being returned from the `useState` function. I introduced a second option variable to prevent the reuse of the option variable overwriting the wrong attribute property, for example - this is pretty ugly!

```
const optionDir = useState( props.attributes.blockType || '' ).option;
```

What is strange is that this does produce the visual affect I require and the appropriate attribute values are stored... but the radio buttons in the RadioControls do lose their selected status... I need to set up both controls so they are independent of each other. Can someone help me achieve and understand this. If it helps here is my attributes object:

```
"attributes": {
    "blockType": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "direction": {
      "type": "string",
      "default": ""
    },
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "strapline": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "copy": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
```

Comment: if you're controlling css modifiers would it not be better to use a block style? Then you'd have dedicated support from core itself, html classes in the markup, a free UI in the sidebar, as well as controls in the block toolbar when clicking on the blocks icon, and the guarantee that the UI will keep working as new releases of WP update things

Comment: also it's a major anti-pattern and common cause of problems to store block attributes in component state. Don't set state, set attributes, state is not stored on a block it's stored on a component and components are destroyed and created all the time. Block state === attributes. Also look at block variants, both variants and styles are the intended way of changing the style of a block, not a custom attribute and radio picker. I'd also advise against putting inputs like this directly in the block, they should go in the block inspector sidebar instead.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will look into "block style"